# Unexpected behaviour when addressing matplotlib subplot in nested list

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using `gridspec` for creating a pattern of subplots I have problems with indexing the individual subplots after creation. For visualisation I am using `text()` as placeholder for any plotting etc. Modifiing the subplot right after creation (V1) works like expected - every plot has a corresponding text.

[image]

However, if the subplot is modified in a sepeart loop (V2) the text only appears stacked in the lower row.

[image]

I need the flexibility of gridspec with the width and height ration instead of the approach using `fig, axes=plt.subplots(2,2)`.

Thanks in advance!

The example is created by the following snippet:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close('all')
fig=plt.figure()
gs=fig.add_gridspec(2,2)
axes=[[None]*2]*2
for col in range(0,2):
    for row in range(0,2):
        axes[row][col]=fig.add_subplot(gs[row,col])
        # V1: Works like expected
        axes[row][col].text(0.5,0.5, 'R:{} C:{}'.format(row, col))
```

The seperate modification:

```
# V2: Text appears only in lower row 
for col in range(0,2):
    for row in range(0,2):   
        axes[row][col].text(0.5,0.5, 'R:{} C:{}'.format(row, col))
```

Comment: Due to how Python tries to save space, `axes=[[None]*2]*2` reuses the same memory.  You could try something like `axes=[[None, None], [None, None]]` instead.  Note that the recommended way to create the axes is via `fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2,nrows=2)`.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the hint. I was not aware, that the `subplots` method has changed within the last versions. With the current (3.6.1) release it offers all the flexibility of `gridspec`

Comment: Most but not all, for example any subplot keywords are shared with all axes, whereas `gridspec` allows subplot-specific keywords. The new `plt.subplot_mosaic` is also worth a try.